# Does Kubernetes have facilities to support zero-downtime deploys when static assets change?

Tags: kubernetes

We have a requirement that no requests receive 404's when doing a rolling deploy. Currently we achieve this by deploying the new assets container to all servers before continuing with a rolling deploy. With nginx's "try_files" this ensures that as the new code is being rolled out we can serve both the old and new versions of assets.  Does Kubernetes have any features to support this type of workflow?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [`Deployment` API](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/) (for Kubernetes >= v1.2) or [`kubectl rolling-update`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/rolling-updates/) (for < v1.2) to manage the rolling deploy of your Kubernetes `Pod`s (each is a co-located group of containers and volumes). You'll also need to create `Service`s for accessing those `Pod`s (`Service`s redirect traffic to `Pod`s). During the rolling deploy, a user will be redirected to either the `Pod` with old or new versions of assets container.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be using [Deployments](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/). You can run a Deployment with several Replica's.

Now when you update to a new version, the Deployment takes care that one old version is removed and a new version is added one after another until your new version is fully rolled out. The rollout strategy can be

When running nginx in your Pod's for serving static files, I would suggest adding the following to your container specification:

```
lifecycle:
  preStop:
    exec:
      command: ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-s", "quit"]
```

This will send a `QUIT` [Signal](http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html) to your nginx before the Pod is getting destroyed. This way you can be sure that no new connections get accepted by nginx, just before the server is going down.